# How to use goog.net.IframeIo to upload a file to Blobstore in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, google-closure

Here I am trying to upload a file **asynchronously** to the blobstore. Following is what I've done so far:

**html file**

```
<form id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"
      action="/partner">
  <input type="file" id="my_file" name="my_file"/>
</form>
```

**js file**

```
my.Project.prototype.onFileUpload = function(e) {
  var uploadForm = /** @type {HTMLFormElement} */ (
          goog.dom.getElement('my_form'));
  var iframeIo = new goog.net.IframeIo();
  goog.events.listen(iframeIo, goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE, function() { alert('request complete'); });
  iframeIo.sendFromForm(uploadForm);
```

**python code**

```
class MyHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    logging.info(self.request)   // I can see my file in this line's output
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('my_file')
    logging.info(upload_files)  //upload_files come out to be an empty array
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    self.redirect('/partner/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
```

Any pointers on how to get the file to be uploaded fron the Request object.
The python code provided by google tutorial on blobstore can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App).

Now I am stuck. I believe if I can get the file in python code I'll be able to upload it.
Any pointers will be very helpful.

Thanks,
Mohit

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a question about iframeio, but simply about uploading in AppEngine. What you're missing is that you're supposed to create a URL to upload to first, in your GET method, and use that as the `action` parameter for the form. See the [sample application](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App) in the AppEngine docs.

So in your case, you'd do `upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/partner')`, and in your template, `<form action="{{ upload_url }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for replying. In sample application, they are creating the URL because first they want the user to land in the MainHandler where a form is created to facilitate file upload. If you see the form, they have provided the created URL in action. In my case I don't want MainHandler. SO I had the action="URL" in my HTML form itself. Also, I can successfully hit the desired handler. The only issue is to get the file out from the request object. I hope this clarifies my problem a bit more.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You need to POST to the URL returned by `create_url`, otherwise the upload will not work. AppEngine will handle the upload, then dispatch to your own method.